# Loop linear regression different predictor and outcome variables

Tags: r, loops, apply, linear-regression

I'm new to R but am slowly learning it to analyse a data set.

Let's say I have a data frame which contains 8 variables and 20 observations. Of the 8 variables, V1 - V3 are predictors and V4 - V8 are outcomes.

```
B = matrix(c(1:160),
nrow = 20,
ncol = 8,)
```

`df <- as.data.frame(B)`

Using the `car` package, to perform a simple linear regression, display summary and confidence intervals is:

```
fit <- lm(V4 ~ V1, data = df)
summary(fit)
confint(fit)
```

How can I write code (`loop` or `apply`) so that R regresses each predictor on each outcome individually and extracts the coefficients and confidence intervals? I realise I'm probably trying to run before I can walk but any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your lines in a lapply call and train a linear model for each of your predictors (excluding the target, of course).

```
my.target <- 4
my.predictors <- 1:8[-my.target]

lapply(my.predictors, (function(i){
  fit <- lm(df[,my.target] ~ df[,i])
  list(summary= summary(fit), confint = confint(fit))
}))
```

You obtain a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks, Damiano. Your solution worked perfectly on the example data. When I apply it in the same way to my own data it returns "Error: Unsupported index type: tbl_df". Does this mean there is something fundamentally different between the example data frame and the that of my research data?

Comment: It suggests you cannot subset your data by index, i.e. df[,i]. So, yes. Can you run `class(tbl_df)` and `str(tbl_df)` and let us know what's the class and structure of your object?

Comment: `> class(tbl_df)` returns `[1] "function"`
`>str(tbl_df)` returns `function (data)`

Comment: OK, so that variable is storing a function and not the data. There's an issue somewhere.. Can you post the code you use to import your data?

Comment: My data is imported from a stata file I had created when I first started working with the data. `metabdata <- read_dta("statadataframe.dta")`

Comment: 1> metabdata is a data.frame? 2> Also, there is a discrepancy between "my_outcomes" and "my_outcome" (final s is missing in the lm() call). 3> Just use numeric indexing if possible...

Comment: `metabdata` is a data.frame. I will try and stick with numeric indexing.

Answer (score 0):

So, the code in my own data that returns the error is:

```
my.target <- metabdata[c(34)]
my.predictors <- metabdata[c(18 : 23)]

lapply(my.predictors, (function(i){
   fit <- lm(metabdata[, my.target] ~ metabdata[, i])
   list(summary = summary(fit), confint = confint(fit))
   }))
```

Returns:

```
Error: Unsupported index type: tbl_df
```